# "Way" vs "Ways" in a specific sentence

Tags: relative-pronouns

I'm not sure if "way" or "ways" is correct in this sentence:

> The ways power is used in factories varies by X, Y, and Z.

With X, Y, and Z describing different features of factories.

The context is a technical document about energy efficiency. This is in an intro, leading to more specifics on *the different ways* factories use energy and can be more efficient. That's why it says "The ways power is used". But it sounds a little odd - should it be "The way power is used"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct. You  find sometimes  an accompanying adjective (several, various, different, many, etc.), as in "the * ways you have". ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+ways+you+have%2Cthe+%2A+ways+you+have&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20ways%20you%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cthe%20%2A%20ways%20you%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20many%20ways%20you%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20different%20ways%20you%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20best%20ways%20you%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20various%20ways%20you%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20more%20ways%20you%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20little%20ways%20you%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20other%20ways%20you%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20two%20ways%20you%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20three%20ways%20you%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20same%20ways%20you%20have%3B%2Cc0))